# How to use index in a query with a lot of joins to make it faster?

Tags: mysql, indexing

So Im trying to make my query faster because it has lot of rows to fetch about 400k of rows.
I want to use an index that if that column is null.
Below is my sample query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT table_1.id,
CONCAT(table_1.firstname, ' ', table_1.lastname) AS fullname,
table_1.firstname,
table_1.lastname,
table_1.email_address,
table_1.telephone,
table_4.description AS organization,
table_5.description AS location,
table_6.description AS department,
CASE
WHEN table_3.description IS NOT NULL THEN table_3.description
ELSE 'General User'
END AS user_role,
table_3.sup_admin,
table_1.employee_id

FROM table_1 

JOIN table_2 ON table_2.sd_users_id = table_1.id
JOIN table_3 ON table_2.sd_menu_user_role_id = table_3.id

LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_4.id = table_1.sd_organization_id
LEFT JOIN table_5 ON table_5.id = table_1.sm_fusion_location_id
LEFT JOIN table_6  ON table_6.id = table_1.sd_department_id

WHERE table_1.status = 'A'

AND table_2.sd_menu_user_role_id IS NULL

GROUP BY table_1.employee_id
ORDER BY email_address ASC
```

AND table_2.sd_menu_user_role_id IS NULL is a filter i use in order to show only General Users as u can see from the case above.

It takes about more than 2 mins to show the result. Someone help me please.

Comment: Prefix the query with "EXPLAIN" clause and post the result. ie. "EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT table1.id,...."

Answer (score 0):

Make indexes at following places

- WHERE clause columns
- columns used at *ON* of JOINS

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense:

```
JOIN table_3
   ON table_2.sd_menu_user_role_id = table_3.id
...
WHERE table_2.sd_menu_user_role_id IS NULL
```

This seems to say that it cannot use `table_3`.  Remove table_3 from that and other places; see if it runs the same, but faster.

Also have this composite index:

```
table_1:  (status, employee_id)  -- in this order
```